# TO DO list in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

There is a handy feature on github markup which can create a nice formatted *TO DO list* and it can be used as follows:

```
- [ ] my first item in list
- [ ] my second item in list
  - [ ] first sub item in second item in list
- [x] my third item in list, already done
```

Which looks like:

[image: github todo list]

Is there anything similar available in `rmarkdown`?

Comment: So far, I don't think so. However, you may use regular nested lists with different "bullets" to distinguish between done and not done.

Comment: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3051

Comment: I think the following could provide a solution. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383140/106804
(if so then perhaps we can close the question).

Answer (score 3):

According to [pandoc tricks](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Tricks),  you may first download the [task-list.lua](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/task-list/task-list.lua) file and save it in
 $DATADIR/pandoc/filters/, so it will be visible to pandoc system-wide, then run pandoc --lua-filter=task-list.lua -o filename.html filename.md